# Delphi Convert returning invalid types

Tags: delphi, units-of-measurement

Im trying to perform the most simple of Conversions in delphi using the built in Convert function.

Simply to convert gallons to litres.

However delphi returns invalid type on the conversion units.

```
procedure TfrmMain.NumberBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
 Result : Double;
begin
  // Update label with result
  Result := Convert(30, vuUKGallons, vuLiters);
  lblAreaResult.Text := Result.ToString;
end;
```

Gallons and litres are in the form as TConvTypes

```
vuUKGallons, vuLiters: TConvType;
```

However delphi returns the following when i try to execute the code.

```
First chance exception at $7603AB32. Exception class EConversionError with message 'Incompatible conversion types [Illegal type, Illegal type]'. Process UnitConverter.exe (13972)
```

This should be the most simple operation after reading through the documentation from Embarcadero the following should just work. At this point i cant figure out what is going on.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks

I have edited the post to include the complete unit code

```
unit frmConverter;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.ListBox, FMX.Layouts,
  FMX.TabControl, FMX.MultiView, FMX.Objects, FMX.Edit, System.ImageList,
  FMX.ImgList, System.Threading, ConvUtils, FMX.EditBox, FMX.NumberBox;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    MultiView1: TMultiView;
    TabControl1: TTabControl;
    tabLength: TTabItem;
    tabVolume: TTabItem;
    tabPressure: TTabItem;
    tabEnergy: TTabItem;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    StyleBook1: TStyleBook;
    tabMass: TTabItem;
    tabTemp: TTabItem;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    cbAreaFrom: TComboBox;
    Label5: TLabel;
    cbAreaTo: TComboBox;
    btnMaster: TButton;
    Label6: TLabel;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Layout1: TLayout;
    lblAreaResult: TLabel;
    Image1: TImage;
    ToolBar1: TToolBar;
    Button1: TButton;
    Image2: TImage;
    Button2: TButton;
    Image3: TImage;
    Button3: TButton;
    Image4: TImage;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Button4: TButton;
    Image5: TImage;
    Label9: TLabel;
    Button5: TButton;
    Image6: TImage;
    Label10: TLabel;
    Button6: TButton;
    Image7: TImage;
    Label11: TLabel;
    Button7: TButton;
    Image8: TImage;
    Label12: TLabel;
    Button8: TButton;
    Image9: TImage;
    Label13: TLabel;
    NumberBox1: TNumberBox;
    lblDebugConvFrom: TLabel;
    lblDebugConvTo: TLabel;
    procedure NumberBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;
  vuUKGallons, vuLiters: TConvType;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TfrmMain.NumberBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
 Result : Double;
begin
  // Update label with result
  Result := Convert(30, vuUKGallons, vuLiters);
  lblAreaResult.Text := Result.ToString;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Perhaps, you have declared the set of *your own* `vuUKGallons` and `vuLiters` elements or ypu have global variables with the same names. Try to explicitly set unit where `TConvTypes` are declared in the following way: `Result := Convert(30, StdConvs.vuUKGallons, StdConvs.vuLiters);`

Comment: I think that @Dima is right. I just tried it myself with no problems. BTW if you had given us a full [MCVE] we could have told you for sure.

Comment: Iv'e just updated the post to include the full unit code. Thanks guys

Comment: Forget about your `TConvType` and use predefined one, which is declared in `System.StdConvs` unit.

Comment: This is a pretty disappointing example program. We expect a [mcve] in this situation. Next time please make an effort to make it minimal. In fact, doing so will make it easier for you to see the problem.

Comment: Thanks Dima. I can see where i went wrong now.

Comment: @Revski, when adding a minimal example, please exclude all GUI stuff and supply a console application.

Answer (score 2):

Your program must be modifying the values of `vuUKGallons` and `vuLiters`, or using different ones. This program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.StdConvs,
  System.ConvUtils;

begin
  Writeln(Convert(30, vuUKGallons, vuLiters));
  Readln;
end.
```

outputs `1.36382700000000E+0002`.

But this program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.StdConvs,
  System.ConvUtils;

begin
  vuUKGallons := 0;
  vuLiters := 0;
  Writeln(Convert(30, vuUKGallons, vuLiters));
end.
```

raises an exception:

```
Incompatible conversion types [Illegal type, Illegal type]
```

As does this program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.StdConvs,
  System.ConvUtils;

var
  vuUKGallons, vuLiters: Word;

begin
  Writeln(Convert(30, vuUKGallons, vuLiters));
end.
```

You must use the `vuXXX` variables defined in the `System.StdConvs` unit.

**Update**

Having seen your complete code, it is now clear what has happened.

- You did not use the `System.StdConvs` unit.
- When you tried to refer to `vuUKGallons` and `vuLiters` the compiler told you that no such symbols existed.
- You declared new variables `vuUKGallons` and `vuLiters`.
- Your code now compiled, but the values of `vuUKGallons` and `vuLiters` are incorrect.

Solve the problem by:

1. Remove the declarations of variables `vuUKGallons` and `vuLiters` in your code.
2. Add the unit `System.ConvUtils` to your uses clause.

Comment: Thanks David. Now i can see. I will give this a try now. My mistake was simply declaring vuXXX separate.